# allow scroll on hovered element which is fixed

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-position, fixed

I have a small navigation box called "server" on https://mineyourmind.net/en/

If you resize the browser to a phones screen size and hover the "server" button, you can´t scroll the appearing content. Only the background is scrolling. How can I fix this ?

---

**Edit:**
According to answer 1

I got it working without javascript (I don´t even know what it changed ?): 
http://jsbin.com/ixura3/393/

---

**Edit2:** current version, problem with a relative height of 100%.

So it looks like this now:
http://jsbin.com/EPiBegiG/1/

How do I get the height of the accordion to 100% of the browser size without javascript.

---

**Solution:**

http://jsbin.com/EPiBegiG/2/

Comment: What is wrong with my question, that it gets down votes ?

Comment: What should I paste here as code ? Isn´t it more clear if you check out the website ?

Comment: ok, I see. In opinion it is easier to look it up with firebug than in jsfiddle. Next time I add the code as this question is answered if thenewseattle answer is right.

Comment: I will, maybe someone knows another solution without javascript. Because JS is no option for me.

Answer (score 0):

It does now work like this, without any javascript:

http://jsbin.com/EPiBegiG/2/

Comment: you dont need to answer your own question. check my answer. it's correct

Comment: sry, but its bad. You said I need Javascript for it to work and there is no need at all.